# Сократить код повторяющихся конструкторов

Tags: java, конструктор

Знатоки.
Я только начинаю программировать, поэтому приходится задавать такие примитивные вопросы.
Вот один из них.

- У меня есть класс который оперирует несколькими переменными.
- Мне крайне не приятно повторять конструктор для каждого варианта определенности переменных. В одном случае конструктор по умолчанию, переменные без определения, в другом, одна переменная задается в конструкторе, в третьем две и так по нарастающей последовательности.
- И каждый раз я вынужден дублировать конструктор, вместо того чтобы внутри конструктора задать условия и соответствующие значения. Т.е. несколько конструкторов заменить одним.
- Я догадываюсь, что практики не повторяют свой код и пользуются одним конструктором с пустыми входящими полями(по умолчанию) и одним с переменным количеством заданных полей.
  -Мне очень интересно как Вы это делаете)))
  Заранее благодарю.
  Всем хорошего настроения.

Пример кода прост:

```
паблик класс Кот() {
    поле 1, поле 2, поле 3;
    конструктор Кот () {}
    конструктор Кот (поле 1, поле 2) {
        зис.поле 1 = поле 1;
        зис.поле 2 = поле 2;
    }
    конструктор Кот (поле 1, поле 2, поле 3) {
        зис.поле 1 = поле 1;
        зис.поле 2 = поле 2;
        зис.поле 3 = поле 3;
    }
    и т.д.
}
```

Comment: Я думаю, что необязательные параметры - это и есть то что нужно. Благодарю.

Comment: Возможно, вам нужен паттерн строитель. Вот даже сайт для онлайн генерации кода, реализующего паттерн: https://riversun.github.io/java-builder/

Comment: Интересно, сколько лет думал, что java и c# отличаются только названием, а тут такое различие в самой обыкновенной вещи. В любом случае, в ответе вам написали правильную реализацию необязательных параметров в java.

Comment: Паттерны на мой взгляд очень помогают с организацией архитектуры в целом. Но это уже будет другой вопрос. Не ожидал такой активности, порадовали меня.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложу другой вариант.

Прошу не холиварить просто вариант. Описывать все getters не стану лишь укажу как пользоваться setter.

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    boolean isMan;

    public Person() {
        
    }

    public String getName(){...}

    public Person setName(String name){ 
      this.name = name;
      return this;
    }

    public int getAge(){...}

    public Person setAge(int age){ 
      this.age = age;
      return this;
    }

    .....
}
```

Тогда создание задание значений будет интересным.

```
Person vasya = new Person().setName('Вася');
Person ivan = new Person().setAge(25).setIsMan(true);
```

По сути у вас пустой конструктор. Он один а свойства задаёте через сеттеры которые паровозиком в любом порядке как хотите.

Вот [статья](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/244521/) использующая подход. Извините все не описал с телефона набираю

Comment: В статье все же другой подход, там внутри класса "сидит" класс-строитель, который создает объект с нужными параметрами.

Comment: Да идея показать, понятно что строитель

Comment: Любопытно получилось, как в ломбоке прямо) В принципе и поломаться ничего не должно, если стандартные сеттеры на такие заменить.

Comment: @Zhenyria да ломаться не должно. Только загвоздка одна. И наследоваться особо не будет методы. Этот подход хорош для простых pojo классов. Для остальных метод не очень. Но как говориться нельзя объять необъятное

Comment: @AzizUmarov ну с тем же ломбоком при наследовании тоже проблемы возникают... Так что нормально

Comment: @Zhenyria ну я думаю вы заметили что я ломбоком не пользуюсь. :))

Comment: @Zhenyria Я бы вообще синтаксически предложил все void методы возвращали this как конструктор за исключением конечно статики :))). И не нужны тогда все эти ломбоки и прочие

Comment: @AzizUmarov да, кстати, в js вроде бы даже что-то похожее где-то встречал. Но вряд ли джаву так радикально менять будут) А ведь в котлине наверное с этим попроще? Там небось и this возвращается, нет?

Comment: @Zhenyria с котлином не знаком

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понимаю, основная проблема в том, что вам не нравится большое количество кода из-за конструкторов. Возможные решения проблемы:

**1.** Создайте один конструктор, который будет принимать все параметры:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    boolean isMan;

    public Person(String name, int age, boolean isMan) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.isMan = isMan;
    }
}
```

А потом создайте конструкторы с нужными вам параметрами, которые будут делегировать создание объекта на этот большой конструктор:

```
  public Person() {
        this("default", 10, true);
    }
    
    public Person(String name) {
        this(name, 10, true);
    }
    
    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this(name, age, true);
    }
```

Кода получится гораздо меньше.

**2.** Если вы хотите передавать в конструктор несколько переменных одного типа, вы можете использовать `varargs`, что выглядит вот так:

```
public Person(String ... properties) {
        this.name = properties[0] != null ? properties[0] : "default";
        ///далее
    }
```

Особенность `varargs` в том, что вы можете передавать в конструктор неопределённое количество элементов *(в том числе и 0)*, а на входе всё это будет конвертироваться в массив.

**3.** Возможно, имеет смысл обратить внимание на статические методы инициализации. С ними вы можете играть вообще как угодно:

```
public static Person createPetya(int age) {
        return new Person("Petya", age, true);
    }
```

Comment: А будет ли - varargs - нагружать скорость выполнения? Если это не влияет, то весьма приятно. Про   делегаты действительно здорово! Заодно попрактикую эту тематику.

Comment: @СаломатинГ.С. не должен. Да, ему потребуется время на создание массива, но вы вряд ли это ощутите, если, конечно, не собираетесь специально замерять.