# как делать несколько конструкторов?

Tags: java

У меня есть класс с 4 аргументами

```
public class Employee {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String salary;
private String department;
```

есть ли способ  в методах, делать разные конструкторы, чтоб один принимал lastName firstname, другой Salary department.

```
  public Employee add(String firstName, String lastName) {
      Employee employee = new Employee(firstName, lastName);
```

чтобы не выдавало "Expected 4 arguments but found 2"

Comment: Понятно ровно ничего

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сократить код повторяющихся конструкторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1209829/), [Что такое телескопический конструктор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1292339/)

Comment: перефразируй вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class Employee {

  private final String firstName;
  private final String lastName;
  private final String salary;
  private final String department;

  public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String salary, String department) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.department = department;
  }

}
```

```java
public Employee add() {
  Employee employee = new Employee("first name", "last name", "salary", "department");
}
```

`Ключевое слово` **this** `представляет ссылку на текущий экземпляр класса. Через это ключевое слово мы можем обращаться к переменным, методам объекта, а также вызывать его конструкторы.`

Comment: а есть ли возможность делать employee чтоб он принимал только lastName и firstName?           Employee employee = new Employee(firstName, lastName);  в данном случае оно ждет 4 аргумента, а мне нужно чтоб только 2 нужных мне в этом методе

Comment: Можно, но тогда остальные переменные будут null в вашем случае

```java
public Employee(String firstName, String lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String salary, String department) {}
```

просто делаешь еще один конструктор

```
public Employee(String firstName, String lastName){}
```

И в зависимости от количества параметров будет вызываться соответствующий конструктор.
Если 4 параметра то первый, если 2 параметра то второй

Answer (score 0):

> *есть ли способ в методах, делать разные конструкторы, чтоб один принимал lastName firstname, другой Salary department.*

"Делать" конструкторы в данном случае не получится, поскольку в данном случае все аргументы/поля в классе `Employee` однотипны (`String`).
Вместо конструкторов можно написать два разных метода-генератора, которые будут вызывать *полный* конструктор с четырьмя аргументами, подставляя некие значения по умолчанию или `null`.

*Замечание: использование **строк** для хранения информации об отделе и особенно о зарплате не самый удачный выбор*

```java
public class Employee {
    private static final String UNKNOWN = "Unknown";

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String salary;
    private String department;

    public Employee(String first, String last, String salary, String dept) {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.department = dept;
    }

    public static Employee byName(String first, String last) {
        return new Employee(first, last, UNKNOWN, null);
    }

    public static Employee bySalaryAndDept(String salary, String dept) {
        return new Employee("John", "Doe", salary, dept);
    }
}
```

Можно даже ограничить видимость общего конструктора, установив `private`, тогда для создания экземпляров `Employee` придётся использовать указанные статические методы-генераторы.

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае (когда все поля одного типа) лучше использовать паттерн Строитель.
https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/builder

То есть Вам необходимо создать конструктор по умолчанию, который будет создавать пустой объект и возвращать ссылку на него. А после вызывать на нем методы `addFirstName`, `addLastName`, `addSalary`, `addDepartment`

```
Employee employee = new Employee().addFirstName("Bob").addSalary("1000");
```

А они будут реализованы следующим способом:

```
public Employee addFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.setFirstName(firstName);
    return this;
}
```